# Rotated tires, now alerted to tire pressure low

Tags: tires, tire-pressure, tire-pressure-monitoring-system

Honda Accord 2020

- I had my tires rotated at 5k miles at dealer.
- When I brought vehicle home, it alerted tire pressure.
- I manually checked tire pressure, all good.
- I reset, I believe, according to manual, tire monitoring system. I do not believe this vehicle has sensors.

Still alerts to low tire pressure.

What else could set off low tire pressure after tire rotation?

Comment: Find out how to reset the relative pressure status on full air p

Comment: Some vehicles use other means to estimate relative tire pressure and warn accordingly.  In ABS equipped vehicles the ABS ring "tone" gives an accurate indication of the relative circumference of the tire.  When the frequency of the tone changes at a given speed, the system can alert you to a possible tire pressure issue.